# When does a const return type interfere with template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, return-value

From Herb Sutter's [GotW #6](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm)

> Return-by-value should normally be const for non-builtin return types. ...
>
> Note: Lakos (pg. 618) argues against returning const value,
>   and notes that it is redundant for builtins anyway
>   (for example, returning "const int"), which he notes may 
>   interfere with template instantiation.

While Sutter seems to disagree on whether to return a const value or non-const value when returning an object of a non-built type by value with Lakos, he generally agrees that returning a const value of a built-in type (e.g const int) is not a good idea.

While I understand why that is useless because the return value cannot be modified as it is an rvalue, I cannot find an example of how that might interfere with template instantiation.

Please give me an example of how having a const qualifier for a return type might interfere with template instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example involving function pointers:

```
const int f_const(int) { return 42; }
int f(int) { return 42; }

template <typename T>
void g(T(*)(T))
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    g(&f_const); // doesn't work:  function has type "const int (*)(int)"
    g(&f);       // works: function has type "int (*)(int)"
}
```

Note that Visual C++ 2010 incorrectly accepts both.  Comeau 4.3.10 and g++ 4.1.2 correctly do not accept the `g(&f_const)` call.