# Why does operator ++ return a non-const value?

Tags: c++, constants, return-value

I have read Effective C++ 3rd Edition written by Scott Meyers.

Item 3 of the book, "Use `const` whenever possible", says if we want to prevent rvalues from being assigned to function's return value accidentally, the return type should be `const`.

For example, the increment function for `iterator`:

```
const iterator iterator::operator++(int) {
    ...
}
```

Then, some accidents is prevented.

```
iterator it; 

// error in the following, same as primitive pointer
// I wanted to compare iterators
if (it++ = iterator()) {
  ...
}
```

However, iterators such as `std::vector::iterator` in GCC don't return `const` values.

```
vector<int> v;
v.begin()++ = v.begin();   // pass compiler check
```

Are there some reasons for this?

Comment: You shouldn't use ++ in any side of a comparison expression anyway.

Comment: Amazing how many wrong answers this got.

Comment: It's now an out-dated trick, because it prevents move-construction. The modern way to do it is to define `operator=` as defaulted using a `&` ref-qualifier.

Comment: If returned iterators were const, then you couldn't increment them, so the iterators wouldn't be iterating.

Comment: @Konrad: Feel free to write what you think is a correct one, rather than just trolling.

Comment: @stefaanv I seem that it is correct not to be able to increment them because we can't increment post incremented pointers.

Comment: @Tom I’m not trolling. Three people before you have already accepted that they misunderstood the question. I *am* being constructive, this is why I changed the title. I don’t answer the question because I *don’t know the answer*. Valid reason, yes?

Comment: @stefaanv: the return value is only used to initialise the iterator used for iteration; this will work whether or not the return value is `const`.

Comment: @Mike: at the time of writing, it wasn't clear that the OP meant that the return value of the post increment operator should be const.  It is clearer now after his answer on my comment.

Comment: @Konrad: "Amazing how many wrong answers this got" is **not** a constructive comment.

Comment: I use double quotes here: "probably because this stuff was written before Meyer's book, and now it's too late to fix it!" There is probably some code in the wild which does exactly what you want to prevent...

Comment: @Nim: "There is probably some code in the wild which does exactly what you want to prevent." +1. This, coupled with the need to be backward compatible if at all possible, is probably the answer to the question.

Comment: See also Herb Sutter's GotW #6, [Const Correctness](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm), which includes the guideline "(Arguable.) Return-by-value should normally be const for non-builtin return types." It has the caveat "Lakos (pg. 618) argues against returning const value, and notes that it is redundant for builtins anyway (for example, returning "const int"), which he notes may interfere with template instantiation." (The only "interference" I could think of is in [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926319/x/2926345#2926345)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is because it would play havoc with rvalue references and any sort of `decltype`. Even though these features were not in C++03, they have been known to be coming.

More importantly, I don't believe that any Standard function returns const rvalues, it's probably something that wasn't considered until after the Standard was published. In addition, const rvalues are generally not considered to be the Right Thing To Do™. Not all uses of non-const member functions are invalid, and returning const rvalues is blanketly preventing them.

For example,

```
auto it = ++vec.begin();
```

is perfectly valid, and indeed, valid semantics, if not exactly desirable. Consider my class that offers method chains.

```
class ILikeMethodChains {
public:
    int i;
    ILikeMethodChains& SetSomeInt(int param) {
        i = param;
        return *this;
    }
};
ILikeMethodChains func() { ... }
ILikeMethodChains var = func().SetSomeInt(1);
```

Should that be disallowed just because maybe, sometimes, we might call a function that doesn't make sense? No, of course not. Or how about "swaptimization"?

```
std::string func() { return "Hello World!"; }
std::string s;
func().swap(s);
```

This would be illegal if `func()` produced a const expression - but it's perfectly valid and indeed, assuming that `std::string`'s implementation does not allocate any memory in the default constructor, both fast and legible/readable.

What you should realize is that the C++03 rvalue/lvalue rules frankly just don't make sense. They are, effectively, only part-baked, and the minimum required to disallow some blatant wrongs whilst allowing some possible rights. The C++0x rvalue rules are much saner and much more *complete*.

Comment: isn't `const rvalue` a tautology? I mean, isn't rvalue, which does not have an address, const by definition?

Comment: @davka: No, they just can't bind to non-const references. They themselves are not const in any way at all.

Comment: Writing about rvalues isn't answering the question. The question asked about why iterator pre- and postincrement operators return lvalues. The rules regarding this question haven't changed with C++11, so I question that the rules much saner and more complete (at least with regard to the question at hand).

Comment: @David Hammen: Rvalues has everything to do with the question, it asks about returning const rvalues to returning non-const rvalues. My answer clearly demonstrates why const rvalues are undesirable, and how C++11 addresses the problems of returning non-const rvalues and keeps all the advantages.

Comment: I think it isn't correct to use post incremented iterators like your examples, but the reasons you indicated are rational and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If `it` is non-const, I expect `*(++it)` to give me mutable access to the thing it represents.</strike>

<strike>However, dereferencing a `const` iterator yields only non-mutable access to the thing it represents.</strike> [**edit:** no, [this is wrong too](http://www.ideone.com/E2iBy). I really give up now!]

<strike>This is the only reason I can think of.</strike>

As you rightly point out, the following is ill-formed because `++` on a primitive yields an rvalue (which can't be on the LHS):

```
int* p = 0;
(p++)++;
```

So there does seem to be something of an inconsistency in the language here.

Comment: This is *also* not what the OP asked (incidentally, where are the other comments explaining this? Deleted?). The `for` loop doesn’t even use the behaviour mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, it is. (And yes, they are.) My final paragraph explains the difference between what the OP thinks a `const iterator` would do, and what it would actually do.. and the reason for what it actually does (which is what he asked for). The loop absolutely uses the behaviour: the question specifically discusses `op++`, which would (should) be impossible on a `const` object. Hard to iterate with something that cannot be used to iterate.

Comment: @Tom I think you are mistaken but you could convince me of the opposite me by explaining what you mean in your answer. Also, notice the changed question title. The question is completely unrelated to iterators (that was just an example), it’s about the return type of `operator ++`. And your comment is wrong, too: `it` *isn’t* `const`. The return value of `++it`, though, is. No problem here.

Comment: @Konrad: _You_ changed the title, during a dispute about what the OP meant. I suggest you leave it up to the OP to clarify, in case you are wrong. That said, I take your point. I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: @Tom I changed the title because it was misleading. I have read the relevant passage in Meyers’ book so I’m confident that I know what he’s actually talking about (and, by inference, what the OP means).

Comment: @Konrad: Knowing what Meyers is talking about is completely orthogonal to knowing what the OP is talking about.

Comment: I'm going to write a new answer. This one will remain for a few minutes to let our conversation finish naturally. :)

Comment: Your edited example would be valid even if `operator++(int)` returned a `const iterator`.

Comment: @Konrad @Tom I think I don't confuse `const iterator` and `const_iterator`. Post incremented primitive pointers can't be incremented, for instances, `int* p; (p++)++;`. But iterators in gcc can.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: *This is not really answering the question as pointed in the comments. I'll just leave the post here in the case it's useful anyhow...*

I think this is pretty much a matter of syntax unification towards a better usable interface. When providing such member functions without differentiating the name and letting only the overload resolution mechanism determine the correct version you prevent (or at least try to) the programmer from making `const` related worries.

I know this might seem contradictory, in particular given your example. But if you think on most of the use cases it makes sense. Take an STL algorithm like `std::equal`. No matter whether your container is constant or not, you can always code something like `bool e = std::equal(c.begin(), c.end(), c2.begin())` without having to think on the right version of begin and end.

This is the general approach in the STL. Remember of `operator[]`... Having in the mind that the containers are to be used with the algorithms, this is plausible. Although it's also noticeable that in some cases you might still need to define an iterator with a matching version (`iterator` or `const_iterator`).

Well, this is just what comes up to my mind right now. I'm not sure how convincing it is...

*Side note*: The correct way to use constant iterators is through the `const_iterator` typedef.

Comment: This is really irrelevant. `std::equal` will take the iterator by value, completely negating any constness that that specific iterator value might have.

Comment: @DeadMG - Maybe you missed the spot...? The point is that if you are in a context in which you have a reference-to-const to a container and you need to call std::equal, for example, you don't have to worry about calling such a c.beginConstVersion() function, you can simply call c.begin() and the compiler will do the trick.

Comment: @Itcmelo: Except that that is done by returning a `const_iterator`, not a `const iterator`. The question, and the semantics behind it, have nothing to do with accessing the container- they're about accessing the *value* returned by a function. That's true irrespective of if it's a reference or a const/mutable reference.