# What's the point of const pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, language-design, const-correctness

I'm not talking about pointers to const values, but const pointers themselves.

I'm learning C and C++ beyond the very basic stuff and just until today I realized that pointers are passed by value to functions, which makes sense. 
This means that inside a function I can make the copied pointer point to some other value without affecting the original pointer from the caller.

So what's the point of having a function header that says:

```
void foo(int* const ptr);
```

Inside such a function you cannot make ptr point to something else because it's const and you don't want it to be modified, but a function like this:

```
void foo(int* ptr);
```

Does the work just as well! because the pointer is copied anyways and the pointer in the caller is not affected even if you modify the copy. So what's the advantage of const?

Comment: What if you want to guarantee, at compile time, that the pointer cannot and should not be modified to point to something else?

Comment: Exactly the same point as any `const` parameter.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, I have a few years of experience programming, yet my software practices are lacking. I'm glad I made this question because I have never felt the need to make the compiler point out my own logic errors. My initial reaction at the moment I submitted the question was "why should I care if the pointer is modified?, it won't affect the caller". Until I read all of the answers I understood that I should care because if I try to modify it, me and my coding logic are wrong (or there was a typo like missing the asterisk) and I might have not realized if the compiler didn't tell me.

Comment: @R.Ruiz. Doubtless, even the most experienced of us could do with extra guarantees of correctness. Because software engineering is a form of engineering where a little more leeway may be acceptable (random HTTP 502s, slow connections, the occasional image failing to load are not extraordinary occasions, but an engine failing in an airplane is unacceptable and likely severe), sometimes people program with undue haste. The same argument that justifies writing unit tests will explain the use of `const`-correctness guarantees. It just makes us feel more sure that our code is indubitably correct.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219914/what-use-are-const-pointers-as-opposed-to-pointers-to-const-objects

Comment: @Raedwald The questions look like exact duplicates to me. There are more good answers on this one, but they all became more general than asked, by talking about `const` on arguments overall, not just pointers.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

`const` is a tool which you should use in pursuit of a very important C++ concept:

> Find bugs at compile-time, rather than run-time, by getting the compiler to enforce what you mean.

Even though it doesn't change the functionality, adding `const` generates a compiler error when you're doing things you didn't mean to do. Imagine the following typo:

```
void foo(int* ptr)
{
    ptr = 0;// oops, I meant *ptr = 0
}
```

If you use `int* const`, this would generate a compiler error because you're changing the value to `ptr`. Adding restrictions via syntax is a good thing in general. Just don't take it too far -- the example you gave is a case where most people don't bother using `const`.

Comment: Thank you, this is an answer that convinces me. You put const so that the compiler warns you about your own assignment errors. Your example is perfect to illustrate this concept because that is a common mistake with pointers. Than you!

Comment: "Help the compiler help you" is the mantra I normally chant for this.

Comment: +1, but here is an interesting case where it is argueable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305906/why-does-operator-return-a-non-const-value

Comment: so it's the same answer you'd give to "Why make variables private, when you can just not use them outside the class."

Comment: this might be a little off topic, but where does this const pointer sit in the memory? I know all const sit in the global part of the memory, but I am not 100% sure about a const that you get passed in as a func var. thanks and sorry if this is off topic

Comment: @tomer - A `const` variable can be local. I think you are confusing with `static`. A static variable, cannot, by its very nature be allocated in the stack. (That comment is a few years old now, though, you may already know that)

Answer (score 84):

I make a point of using *only* `const` arguments because this enables more compiler checks: if I accidentally re-assign an argument value inside the function, the compiler bites me.

I rarely reuse variables, it’s cleaner to create new variables to hold new values, so essentially *all* my variable declarations are `const` (except for some cases such as loop variables where `const` would prevent the code from working).

Note that this makes only sense in the *definition* of a function. It doesn’t belong in the *declaration*, which is what the user sees. And the user doesn’t care whether I use `const` for parameters inside the function.

Example:

```
// foo.h
int frob(int x);
```

```
// foo.cpp
int frob(int const x) {
   MyConfigType const config = get_the_config();
   return x * config.scaling;
}
```

Notice how both the argument and the local variable are `const`. Neither is *necessary* but with functions that are even slightly larger, this has repeatedly saved me from making mistakes.

Comment: `+1` from another `const`-obsessed fanatic. However, I prefer my compilers to bark at me. I make too many errors and would suffer to badly would they bite.

Comment: +1, I highly recommend the "`const` unless there's a good reason" strategy. There are some good exceptions though, e.g. [Copy and swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: If I were designing a new language, declared objects would be read-only ("const") by default.  You'd need some special syntax, perhaps a "var" keyword, to make an object writable.

Comment: @Keith I’m tempted to say “of course”. Everything else is stupid at this point. But unfortunately most language designers seem to disagree with us … In fact, I’ve already posted as much (in a now deleted question, “What’s your most controversial programming opinion?”).

Comment: The "constant unless noted otherwise" approach is common in most functional languages (`let a = ... in ...`), where you need to explicitly create "references" to be allowed to modify variables (`let a = ref ... in ...`).

Comment: In C++11, if you need an internal copy of a function parameter, then having the copy done while the parameter is passed by value exposes additional optimization possibilities. When you need a copy, passing const values as arguments is a premature pessimization in C++11.

Comment: @KubaOber That isn't specific to C++11, the same was true to a lesser extent before.

Comment: @KubaOber I don't see how it's a pessimisation at all. If you later find that you need to modify what was passed within the body of the function, then just drop the `const` from the argument, and preferably comment why. That tiny extra bit of work doesn't justify marking all arguments as non-`const` by default and opening yourself up to all the potential errors that creates.

Comment: Of course you can change the signature if you are allowed to change signatures, and if you have some sort of a process in place to ensure that such changes don't cause regressions.

Comment: @KubaOber `const`ness of an argument isn't part of the public API, it's an implementation detail. You can change it without even recompiling the client code. Reread the answer.

Comment: Any discussion of whether `const`ness of an argument is part of the API or not is impossible without selecting an ABI, because the API is-the ABI in this discussion. From the point of view of C++ standard, any such signature change without recompilation is undefined behavior, so you'd have to argue that a certain ABI allows it. It's brittle at the very least.

Comment: @KubaOber You're wrong, this is specified by the language, and it's *not* a change in signature. **Reread the answer**.

Comment: I was arguing from the point of the answer being wrong. Alas it's not. Now that I've dug into the standard - good to learn that I was wrong. Cool stuff, easy to miss unless you know what you're looking for. Alas, it unfortunately exposes another can of worms: for values that are not cheap to copy, the implementation will leak as you switch from `const T &` to `T` and those definitely are never ABI compatible :(

Comment: Excellent point: the user doesn’t care whether I use const for parameters inside the function.

Comment: I'm pretty late to this discussion but I have a question for this way of coding. Constantly, (pun intended) using const makes a lot of sense to me, but how would you go about a variable with a switch case? Like if you want a value to be equal to something specific based on a statement that can have more answers than a true or false? Like I want to assign a specific string value based on the value of an int and I might want to check for 5 different values.

Comment: @Alex It’s become somewhat of an established pattern in this situation to push the `switch` statement into a function (or lambda), directly `return` the corresponding values from each `case`, and initialise the actual variable with an invocation to that function/lambda. You can even do this inline: `T const x = ([&]() {switch (foo) {case 'a': return 1; case 'b': return 2; …}})();` (properly formatted and broken across several lines, of course!)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Wow that's really nice, I didn't think of that. Is that applied in all C++ industries? I'm studying in the Game Development industry and I'm not sure if there are different coding practices among things of this nature between different fields.

Comment: @Alex I can’t answer that, I never worked in game development and I vaguely know that there are different practices prevalent there. But besides this, it’s a somewhat-widespread pattern.

Answer (score 20):

Your question touches on something more general: Should function arguments be const?

The constness of value arguments (like your pointer) is an **implementation detail**, and it does **not** form part of the function declaration. This means that your function is always this:

```
void foo(T);
```

It is entirely up to the *implementer* of the function whether she wants to use the functions-scope argument variable in a mutable or in a constant way:

```
// implementation 1
void foo(T const x)
{
  // I won't touch x
  T y = x;
  // ...
}

// implementation 2
void foo(T x)
{
  // l33t coding skillz
  while (*x-- = zap()) { /* ... */ }
}
```

So, follow the simple rule to never put `const` in the declaration (header), and put it in the definition (implementation) if you don't want or need to modify the variable.

Comment: I agree with this -- but I'm somewhat uncomfortable with the idea of making the declaration and definition different.  For things other than `const`, the declaration and the (prototype part of) the definition are generally going to be identical.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, you don't have to do it if you don't want to. Just don't put `const` in the declaration. It's entirely up to you if you want to add the qualifier in the implementation.

Comment: As I said, I agree that putting `const` on the declaration but not the definition makes sense.  It just feels like a glitch in the language that this is the only case where making the declaration and definition non-identical makes sense.  (It's hardly C's only glitch, of course.)

Answer (score 18):

There is a lot to the `const` keyword, it is a rather complex one. Generally, adding a lot of const to your program is considered good programming practice, search the web for "const correctness" and you'll find plenty of info about that.

The const keyword is a so-called "type qualifier", others are `volatile` and `restrict`. At least volatile follows the same (confusing) rules as const.

---

First of all, the const keyword serves two purposes. The most obvious one is to protect data (and pointers) from intentional or accidental misuse by making them read-only. Any attempt to modify a const variable will be spotted by the compiler at compile-time.

But there is also another purpose in any system with read-only memory, namely to ensure that a certain variable is allocated inside such memory - it could be EEPROM or flash for example. These are known as non-volatile memories, NVM. A variable allocated in NVM will still of course follow all the rules of a const variable.

There are several different ways to use the `const` keyword:

**Declare a constant variable.**

This can be done either as

```
const int X=1; or
int const X=1;
```

These two forms are *completely equivalent*. The latter style is considered bad style and should not be used.

The reason why the second row is considered bad style, is probably because "storage-class specifiers" such as static and extern also can be declared *after* the actual type, `int static` etc. But doing so for storage-class specifiers is labelled as an obsolete feature by the C committee (ISO 9899 N1539 draft, 6.11.5). Therefore, for the sake of consistency one should not write type qualifiers in that manner either. It serves no other purpose but to confuse the reader anyhow.

**Declare a pointer to a constant variable.**

```
const int* ptr = &X;
```

This means that the contents of 'X' cannot be modified. This is the normal way you declare pointers like this, mainly as part of function parameters for "const correctness". Because 'X' doesn't actually have to be declared as const, it could be any variable. In other words you can always "upgrade" a variable to const. Technically, C also allows downgrading from const to a plain variable by explicit typecasts, but doing so is considered bad programming and compilers usually give warnings against it.

**Declare a constant pointer**

```
int* const ptr = &X;
```

This means that the pointer *itself* is constant. You can modify what it points at, but you cannot modify the pointer itself. This doesn't have many uses, there are a few, like ensuring that a pointer-pointed-at (pointer-to-pointer) doesn't have it's address changed while passed as parameter to a function. You'll have to write something not-too-readable like this:

```
void func (int*const* ptrptr)
```

I doubt many C programmers can get the const and * right in there. I know *I* can't - I had to check with GCC. I think that's why you rarely ever see that syntax for pointer-to-pointer, even though it is considered good programming practice.

Constant pointers can also be used to ensure that the pointer variable itself is declared in read-only memory, for example you could want to declare some sort of pointer-based lookup table and allocate it in NVM.

And of course, as indicated by other answers, constant pointers can also be used to enforce "const correctness".

**Declare a constant pointer to constant data**

```
const int* const ptr=&X;
```

This is the two pointer types described above combined, with all attributes of them both.

**Declare a read-only member function (C++)**

Since this is tagged C++, I should also mention that you can declare member functions of a class as const. This means that the function isn't allowed to modify any other member of the class when it is called, which both prevents the programmer of the class from accidental errors but also informs the caller of the member function that they won't be messing anything up by calling it. The syntax is:

```
void MyClass::func (void) const;
```

Answer (score 17):

The top level const qualifier is discarded in declarations, so the declarations in the question declare exactly the same function. On the other hand, in the *definition* (implementation) the compiler will verify that if you mark the pointer as const, it is not modified inside the body of the function.

Comment: I didn't know that. So if I try to overload void foo(int* const ptr) with void foo(int* t ptr) I will get a compiler error. Thanks!

Comment: @R.Ruiz. If your deceleration is void foo(int* t ptr) and your definition is void foo(int* const ptr), you will NOT get a compiler error.

Comment: @TrevorHickey They will... but not for the reason they think. `int* t ptr` is a syntax error. Without that, the two are identical for overloading purposes.

Answer (score 14):

You're right, for the caller it makes absolutely no difference. But for the writer of the function it can be a safety net "okay, I need to make sure I don't make this point to the wrong thing". Not very useful but not useless either.

It's basically the same as having an `int const the_answer = 42` in your program.

Comment: What does it matter where they point it, it is a pointer allocated on the stack? The function can't mess that up. It makes far more sense to use read-only pointers when dealing with pointer-to-pointers. It is _not_ the same thing as int const! I'll downvote this just for that misleading statement. `const int` and `int const` are equivalent, while `const int*`and `int* const` have two different meanings!

Comment: @lundin Let's suppose the function is big and has other stuff in it. Accidentally one may make it point to something else (on the stack of the function). This isn't problematic for the caller but certainly could be for the callee. I don't see anything misleading in my statements: "**for the writer of the function** it can be a safety net".

Comment: @Lundin About `int const` part; I have been putting the type before const (it does sound unnatural) for some time and I am aware of the differences. [This article](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/231601151) might prove useful. I myself had slightly different reasons to switch to this style however.

Comment: Okay. I just wrote a long-winded answer of my own in case someone else but you and me are reading this post. I also included a rationale why int const is bad style and const int is good style.

Comment: Lundin, I'm also reading! I agree const int is the better style though. @cnicutar, your first response to Lundin is what I was looking for when I submitted this question. So the problem is not in the caller (as I mindlessly thought), but const is an assurance for the callee. I like this idea, thank you.

Comment: Type qualifiers should be written in the same manner as storage class specifiers, or your coding style is illogical and inconsistent. Do you also write `int extern`, `int static`? I bet you don't, and you shouldn't, since this style is also going to be removed from the C language (see my answer to the OP for details).

Comment: @cnicutar No, Saks tends to write only nonsense and that article is no exception. Does `typedef char* ntcs; const ntcs s;` give a const pointer or pointer to const? The answer: muppets hiding away their pointers inside typedefs deserve all the bugs they get.

Answer (score 8):

> ...today I realized that pointers are passed by value to functions, which makes sense.

(imo) it really doesn't make sense as the default. the more sensible default is to pass as non-reassignable pointer (`int* const arg`). that is, i would have preferred that pointers passed as arguments were implicitly declared const.

> So what's the advantage of const?

the advantage is that it's easy enough and sometimes unclear when you do modify the address the argument points to, such that you can introduce a bug when it is not const rather easily. altering the address is atypical. it's clearer to create a local variable if your intent is to modify the address. as well, raw pointer manipulation is an easy way to introduce bugs.

so it's clearer to pass by immutable address and create a copy (in those atypical cases) when you want to alter the address the argument points to:

```
void func(int* const arg) {
    int* a(arg);
    ...
    *a++ = value;
}
```

adding that local is virtually free, and it reduces the chance for errors, while improving readability.

at a higher level: if you are manipulating the argument as an array, it's typically clearer and less error prone to the client to declare the argument as a container/collection.

in general, adding const to values, arguments, and addresses is a good idea because you don't always realize the side effects, which the compiler happily enforces. therefore, it's as useful as const as used in other several other cases (e.g. the question is similar to 'Why should I declare values const?'). fortunately, we also have references, which cannot be reassigned.

Comment: +1 for this being the default. C++, like most languages, has it the wrong way round. Instead of having a `const` keyword, it should have a `mutable` keyword (well, it has, but with the wrong semantics).

Comment: Interesting idea having const as the default. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

Same question can be asked about any other type (not just pointers):

```
/* Why is n const? */
const char *expand(const int n) {
    if (n == 1) return "one";
    if (n == 2) return "two";
    if (n == 3) return "three";
    return "many";
}
```

Comment: LOL, you are right. The case of pointers came to my mind first because I thought they were special, but they are just like any other variable passed by value.

Answer (score 6):

If you do embedded systems or device driver programming where you have memory mapped devices then both forms of 'const' are often used, one to prevent the pointer from being reassigned (since it points to a fixed hardware address.) and, if the peripheral register it points to is a read-only hardware register then another const will detect a lot of errors at compile time rather than runtime.

A read-only 16 bit peripheral chip register might look something like:

`static const unsigned short *const peripheral = (unsigned short *)0xfe0000UL;`

Then you can easily read the hardware register without having to resort to assembly language:

`input_word = *peripheral;`

Answer (score 5):

int iVal = 10;
int *const ipPtr = &iVal;

Just like a normal const variable, a const pointer must be initialized to a value upon declaration, and its value can not be changed.

This means a const pointer will always point to the same value. In the above case, ipPtr will always point to the address of iVal. However, because the value being pointed to is still non-const, it is possible to change the value being pointed to via dereferencing the pointer:

*ipPtr = 6; // allowed, since pnPtr points to a non-const int

Answer (score 5):

Your question is really more about why define any variable as a const not just const pointer parameter to a function. The same rules apply here as when you define any variable as constant, if its a parameter to function or member variable or a local variable.

In your particular case, functionally it doesn't make difference like in many other cases when you declare a local variable as const but it does put a restriction that you can't modify this variable.

Comment: your comment makes realize how futile is my question because you are right: it is the same thing as having any other parameter as const. It may seem useless but it's there to help the programmer have this restriction and avoid bugs

Answer (score 4):

Passing a const pointer to a function makes little sense, as it will be passed by value anyways. It's just one of those things that are allowed by the general language design. Prohibiting it just because it doesn't make sense would just make the language spec. larger.

If you are inside a function it is of course another case. Having a pointer that cannot change what it points to is an assertion that makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I guess an advantage would be that the compiler can perform more aggressive optimizations inside the function knowing that this pointer cannot change.

It also avoids eg. passing this pointer to a subfunction which accepts a non-const pointer reference (and could therefore change the pointer like `void f(int *&p)`), but I agree, that the usefulness is somewhat limited in this case.

Comment: +1 for the optimizations. At least the books say it's true. What I would like is to understand exactly what those optimizations are

Answer (score 4):

An example of where a const pointer is highly applicable can be demonstrated thusly. Consider you have a class with a dynamic array inside it, and you want to pass the user access to the array but without granting them the rights to change the pointer. Consider:

```
#include <new>
#include <string.h>

class TestA
{
    private:
        char *Array;
    public:
        TestA(){Array = NULL; Array = new (std::nothrow) char[20]; if(Array != NULL){ strcpy(Array,"Input data"); } }
        ~TestA(){if(Array != NULL){ delete [] Array;} }

        char * const GetArray(){ return Array; }
};

int main()
{
    TestA Temp;
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
    Temp.GetArray()[0] = ' '; //You can still modify the chars in the array, user has access
    Temp.GetArray()[1] = ' '; 
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
}
```

Which produces:

> Input data
>     put data

But if we try this:

```
int main()
{
    TestA Temp;
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
    Temp.GetArray()[0] = ' ';
    Temp.GetArray()[1] = ' ';
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
    Temp.GetArray() = NULL; //Bwuahahahaa attempt to set it to null
}
```

We get:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment //Drat foiled again!

So clearly we can modify the array's contents, but not the array's pointer. Good if you want to make sure the pointer has a consistent state when passing it back to the user. There is one catch, though:

```
int main()
{
    TestA Temp;
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
    Temp.GetArray()[0] = ' ';
    Temp.GetArray()[1] = ' ';
    printf("%s\n",Temp.GetArray());
    delete [] Temp.GetArray(); //Bwuahaha this actually works!
}
```

We can still delete the pointer's memory reference, even if we can't modify the pointer itself.

So if you want the memory reference to always point to something (IE never be modified, similar to how a reference currently works), then it's highly applicable. If you want the user to have full access and modify it, then non-const is for you.

**Edit:**

After noting okorz001 comment of not being able to assign due to GetArray() being a right-value operand, his comment is entirely correct, but the above still applies if you were to return a reference to the pointer (I suppose I assumed GetArray was referring a reference), for example:

```
class TestA
{
    private:
        char *Array;
    public:
        TestA(){Array = NULL; Array = new (std::nothrow) char[20]; if(Array != NULL){ strcpy(Array,"Input data"); } }
        ~TestA(){if(Array != NULL){ delete [] Array;} }

        char * const &GetArray(){ return Array; } //Note & reference operator
        char * &GetNonConstArray(){ return Array; } //Note non-const
};

int main()
{
    TestA Temp;
    Temp.GetArray() = NULL; //Returns error
    Temp.GetNonConstArray() = NULL; //Returns no error
}
```

Will return in the first resulting in an error:

> error: assignment of read-only location 'Temp.TestA::GetArray()'

But the second will occur merrily despite potential consequences on the underneath.

Obviously, the question will be raised 'why would you want to return a reference to a pointer'? There are rare instances where you need to assign memory (or data) directly to the original pointer in question (for example, building your own malloc/free or new/free front-end), but in those instances it's a non-const reference. A reference to a const pointer I've not come across a situation that would warrant it (unless maybe as declared const reference variables rather than return types?).

Consider if we have a function that takes a const pointer (versus one that doesn't):

```
class TestA
{
    private:
        char *Array;
    public:
        TestA(){Array = NULL; Array = new (std::nothrow) char[20]; if(Array != NULL){ strcpy(Array,"Input data"); } }
        ~TestA(){if(Array != NULL){ delete [] Array;} }

        char * const &GetArray(){ return Array; }

        void ModifyArrayConst(char * const Data)
        {
            Data[1]; //This is okay, this refers to Data[1]
            Data--; //Produces an error. Don't want to Decrement that.
            printf("Const: %c\n",Data[1]);
        }

        void ModifyArrayNonConst(char * Data)
        {
            Data--; //Argh noo what are you doing?!
            Data[1]; //This is actually the same as 'Data[0]' because it's relative to Data's position
            printf("NonConst: %c\n",Data[1]);
        }
};

int main()
{
    TestA Temp;
    Temp.ModifyArrayNonConst("ABCD");
    Temp.ModifyArrayConst("ABCD");
}
```

The error in the const produces thus message:

> error: decrement of read-only parameter 'Data'

Which is good as we probably don't want to do that, unless we want to cause the problems denoted in the comments. If we edit out the decrement in the const function, the following occurs:

> NonConst: A
>   Const: B

Clearly, even though A is 'Data[1]', it's being treated as 'Data[0]' because the NonConst pointer permitted the decrement operation. With the const implemented, as another person writes, we catch the potential bug before it occurs.

One other main consideration, is that a const pointer can be used as a pseudo reference, in that the thing the reference points to cannot be changed (one wonders, if perhaps this was how it was implemented). Consider:

```
int main()
{
    int A = 10;
    int * const B = &A;
    *B = 20; //This is permitted
    printf("%d\n",A);
    B = NULL; //This produces an error
}
```

When attempting to compile, produces the following error:

> error: assignment of read-only variable 'B'

Which is probably a bad thing if a constant reference to A was wanted. If `B = NULL` is commented out, the compiler will happily let us modify `*B` and therefore A. This might not seem useful with ints, but consider if you had a single stance of a graphical application where you wanted an unmodifiable pointer that referred to it that you could pass around.

It's usage is variable (excuse the unintended pun), but used correctly, it is another tool in the box to assist with programming.

Comment: `Temp.GetArray() = NULL` fails because `Temp.GetArray()` is an rvalue, not because it is const-qualified. Additionally, I believe the const-qualifier is stripped from all return types.

Comment: @okorz001: After testing, you are indeed correct. However, the above applies if you return a reference to the pointer itself. I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about pointers where you would never want them to be const. Just as you can have class member constant `int` values, you can also have constant pointers for similar reasons: You want to make sure that no one ever changes what's being pointed to. C++ references somewhat address this, but the pointer behavior is inherited from C.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would prevent code from incrementing or decrementing the pointer within the function body.

Answer (score 3):

**Types of declaring any variables like-**
    (1)Declaring a constant variable.
         `DataType const varibleName;

               int const x;
    x=4; //you can assign its value only One time`  
(2)Declare a pointer to a constant variable
  `const dataType* PointerVaribleName=&X;

               const int* ptr = &X;
     //Here pointer variable refer contents of 'X' that is const Such that its cannot be modified`  
  `dataType* const PointerVaribleName=&X;

               int* const ptr = &X;
     //Here pointer variable itself is constant  Such that value of 'X'  can be modified But pointer can't be modified`

Comment: We provide a pointer variable as a const into a function as an argument   when we don't wana to change its actual value