# Is it a good idea of maintaining "const-ness" as much as possible?

Tags: c++, coding-style, constants

Recently, I have been developing a practice of making many things in my code as `const`:

(1) **Arguments to function**, which I know never going to be changed. e.g.:

```
void foo (const int i, const string s)
          ^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

(2) **Return types** as `const`. e.g.:

```
struct A {
...
  const int foo () { return ...; }
  ^^^^^
  operator const bool () const { return ...; }
           ^^^^^
};
```

(3) **Trivial computation** of integer or strings. e.g.:

```
const uint size = vec.size();
^^^^^
const string s2 = s1 + "hello ";
^^^^^
```

... and few more places. Typically in other real world codes, I don't see such small scale variables marked as `const`. But I thought, making them `const` will never harm. Is it a good **programming practice** ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715371/whats-the-point-of-const-pointers/7715486#7715486

Comment: I still like to use it for objects passed by value, I like my parameters to indicate the original value that was passed in. I hate debugging nested functions where the value of `i` changes from one function to the next. At least if a new variable was used you could spot it more easily.

Comment: @MarkIngram: so basically you're saying that you prefer `unsigned plus(const unsigned a, const unsigned b) { if (b) return plus(a+1,b-1); return a; }` to `unsigned plus(unsigned a, unsigned b) { if (b) { ++a; --b; return plus(a,b) } return a; }`? Because in the second code it could look at a glance as if you're passing your arguments on to the next function (which in this case is a recursive function), when in fact you're passing modified values? Sounds fair enough.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any need to modify the variables in that (second) example.

Comment: see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16835004/819272) for why const return types are not a good idea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(1) and (3) are closely related. A by-value parameter is just a local variable with that name, as is the result of your computation.

Usually it makes little difference in short functions whether you mark local variables `const` or not, since you can see their entire scope right in front of you. You can see whether or not the value changes, you don't need or want the compiler to enforce it.

Occasionally it does help, however, since it protects you from accidentally passing them to a function that takes its parameter by non-const reference, without realising that you're modifying your variable. So if you pass the variable as a function argument during its life, then marking it `const` can give you more confidence that you know what value it has afterwards.

*Very occasionally*, marking a variable `const` can help the optimizer, since you're telling it that the object is never modified, and sometimes that's true but the compiler can't otherwise prove it. But it's probably not worth doing it for that reason, because in most cases it makes no difference.

(2) is another matter. For built-in types it makes no difference, as others have explained. For class types, *do not* return by const value. It might seem like a good idea, in that it prevents the user writing something pointless like `func_returning_a_string() += " extra text";`. But it also prevents something which is pointful -- C++11 move semantics. If `foo` returns a const string, and I write `std::string s = "foo"; if (condition) s = foo();`, then I get copy assignment at `s = foo();`. If `foo` returns a non-const string then I get move assignment.

Similarly in C++03, which doesn't have move semantics, it prevents the trick known as "swaptimization" - with a non-const return value I can write `foo().swap(s);` instead of `s = foo();`.

Comment: Interesting about the swapping optimization. But are there really no legitimate cases to return a class by const value? Returning as const gives the caller an object with more restrictive access that takes away more than just swap...might there be operations that are being taken away for a good reason? I recognize that if one is returning a class by value that "says something" about its usage and that it should probably be copyable, I'm just wondering if there's a proof statement saying that returning it const never has a point? If there's no const assign/construct the const actually "sticks".

Comment: @HostileFork: there's probably a special case somewhere - some kind of proxy object, perhaps, that the user isn't supposed to care about other than that it allows some expression that's needed to satisfy a concept. But if the object has vaguely normal value semantics, and you return a `const` instance, then the user *could* just copy it to their own non-const instance, and mutate that. Since they can do that, I think it's more convenient all round if they can just mutate the return value itself, which is also "theirs" in the sense that it's a temporary in their expression.

Comment: @SteveJessop That's what I mentioned in my answer: if there's const assignment and copy constructor there's hardly a point to trying to const-ify it.  So perhaps that's a good litmus test...

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

It is always a good programming practice to express your intents in the programming language. You don't intend to change the variable, so make it const. Later on, when your compiler yells at you that you can't modify it when it is const, you will be happy that the compiler spotted some wrong ideas of your own design. This is not only true for const, but also for many other things, which is e.g. why in C++11 the `override` keyword was introduced.

Of course there are cases where const will not change anything, like when you return an `int`, but just like in other safety areas: better to have one const too much (that you might remove later because it wasn't really needed), than to have one too little (which will suddenly break stuff silently).

Answer (score 3):

`const`s on scalar return types are ignored, because there is no such thing as a scalar const rvalue.

That is, the following two declarations are exactly equivalent:

```
int foo();
const int foo();   // this particular const is ignored by the compiler
```

If you think about it, this makes sense: you cannot write `foo() = 42;` without the `const`, anyway.

Comment: +1, you are correct. However, I am not able to recall, but long time ago I noticed somewhere that `foo() = 42;` was silently working in some compiler (may be bad compiler). That made me paranoid about `return` type as well!

Answer (score 2):

Const correctness is, in general, important -- but the examples you are using are not really the places it matters. For example:

```
void foo (const int i, const string s)
```

I would be so bold as to declare this prototype *wrong*. If you just had the prototype

```
void foo (int i, string s)
```

then this is *already* a promise not to modify the values the user passes in for `i` and `s`. (since you get *copies* of those values, rather than references to the original) So, the only thing that `const` does in this case is to request the compiler to complain if you accidentally tried to modify `i` or `s`. But there are other ways to achieve this effect -- it doesn't really have any business being exposed externally.

Now, the following use of `const` would actually be useful:

```
void foo (int i, const string &s)
```

this retains your promise not to modify `s`, but now you get a performance benefit because it no longer involves a copy of `s` being made.

Some of the other uses are fine:

```
const size_t size = vec.size();
```

this is good. (once you replace `uint` with `size_t`) There isn't a performance benefit to it here, but it's self-documenting and can protect you against silly accidents.

```
const string s2 = s1 + "hello ";
```

This is good as well. Although again I might make it a reference instead:

```
const string &s2 = s1 + "hello ";
```

This one

```
operator const bool () const { return ...; }
```

is most irrelevant. You should probably implement `operator bool` instead of `operator const bool` even if for no reason other than the former is what people expect.

But it could matter for classes who have non-const versions. Returning `const`, then is not a matter of taste or style, but instead a declaration "I'm going to return to you a new object, but you're not allowed to call any of its non-const functions". This is usually a bad idea -- only make it `const` if you really mean to make that declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is, at least for code that needs to stay maintainable in the long run.

If you'd like to learn more about this, the book "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers shows numeous scenarios where you need const return types and and method arguments to secure your code against misuse.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int x;
public:
    Foo () : x (0) { }
    Foo (const Foo& other) { x = other.x; }
    void setX(const int newX) {
        x = newX;
    }
    const int getX() const {
        return x;
    }
    const Foo getFoo() const {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Making getX() return a `const int` vs an `int` is silly.  Any POD return-by-value type as const is pointless.  Why would it matter?  The only thing you can do to non-const POD variables you can't do to const ones is assignment...and the lvalue/rvalue distinction takes care of that for return types.

By contrast, when it's a return-by-value *object*, const can make a difference...because there may be operations you can perform on a non-const object that you can't on a const one.  This can be undermined by a const copy constructor, though.  Let's take getFoo() for example:

```
Foo foo;
/* foo.getFoo().setX(10); */ // ERROR!
// because f.getFoo() returns const Foo

Foo bar;
bar = foo.getFoo();
bar.setX(10); // no error
```

Making a by-value POD parameter type const protects against modifications of that parameter inside the function.  So for instance, you can't assign a value to `newX` inside of `setX`.

All things being equal that would be all right...as it's a sort-of confusing practice to take an int parameter and change it inside the function; if you are debugging and want to know what the function was called with you have to go up the call stack to find out.  But all things are not equal because it's more typing and screen clutter.

Similarly, making local POD variables const is more typing and clutter for less payoff.  I only use it on globals.

So to me, I say const should be reserved for objects that have truly different semantic method dispatch (often indicated by lack of a const copy constructor)...or globals.  Otherwise it's just getting in the way for minor or no benefit.

Comment: @curiousguy Are you asking for a definition?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Comment: No. But you may check the definition, and your answer.

Comment: @curiousguy You may also stop downvoting sans explanation and acting esoteric, and write actual coherent comments.  Funny how when I find something I don't understand, I go "Hmm, what do you mean?" and outreach sincerely, and you demonstrate your ill will in response.  Very..."funny".

Comment: @curiousguy Glad it's just between you and me.  Seriously dude, is it that hard to actually explain yourself instead of saying "go read a book, kid"?  I swear.  Internet people.

Comment: "_Any **POD** return-by-value type as const is pointless. Why would it matter?_" do you mean fundamental type?

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Arguments to function, which I know never going to be changed.

The only reason to make arguments passed by-value `const` is that you may want to avoid that you accidentally change the value of the copy inside your function, as in:

```
void f( int x ) {
  x += 2;
  // OOPS: At this point 'x' is actually not what the caller passed to us!
}
```

This cannot happen if you pass the argument as `const int x`. However, I know plenty of code where the programmer *intentionally* passes an argument as a value but not const, because he *wants* to modify the argument - otherwise he'd make an copy anyway. I.e. instead of

```
void f( const std::string &s ) {
    std::string s2 = s;
    s2[0] = 'A';
    // ...
}
```

they do

```
void f( std::string s ) {
    s[0] = 'A';
    // ...
}
```

The nice side effect of deliberately tinkering with the copy of the value like this is that you don't have to think about annoying naming issues (should the argument be `s_` and the sanitized value is `s`? Or `s2` vs. `s`, or what?).

Since the presence or absence of the `const` here doesn't influence the caller at all (you're getting a copy of the value anyway, so you can't tinker with the caller's data), it simply boils down to: sometiems it makes sense. Sometimes it doesn't. No good guideline here. My personal feeling is that you shouldn't bother though. If you want to make the argument `const` to avoid that you *accidentally* oevrwrite it, then maybe your function is too long in the first place (or the argument name is silly, like `i` or `tmp` or `it` something like that).

> (2) Return types as const.

This only makes sense if you think there's a chance that callers of your code might *accidentally* attempt to modify the value returned by your function, like this:

```
QString f() { return "Hello"; }
```

If you'd like to forbid `f.strip()` or other mutating calls, you can make the `return` type `const`. I once knew a nice example for a case where returning an object as a non-const value actually allowed some fairly surprising client code. Unfortunately I cannot remember it anymore.

> (3) Trivial computation of integer or strings.

This is actually exactly the same case as (1) which I discussed above. The same reasoning applies.