# Isn't the const modifier here unnecessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, constants, rvalue

The "*Effective C++*" Item 3 says "Use  const whenever possible", and it gives an example like:

```
const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, 
                            const Rational& rhs);
```

to prevent clients from being able to commit atrocities like this:

```
Rational a, b, c;
...
(a * b) = c;   // invoke operator= on the result of a*b!
```

But isn't the non-reference return value of functions allready a ***rvalue***? So why bother doing this?

Comment: Well, without the `const`, that assignment will compile...

Comment: Since `a * b` returns a `const  Rational` you cannot do `= c` on it. But I disagree on returning `const` values from operators.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Why, the non-reference return value is definitely a **rvalue**, which can NOT used as a left operand in = expressions

Comment: @zoujyjs you can invoke member functions on rvalues.

Comment: Am I just overinterpreting or did you chose the title's grammar as a stylistic device to emphasize the question?

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry, my mistake. Thank you~

Comment: @zoujyjs Still leaving it as is would have worked, too.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The point is that for **class types** (but not for builtin types), `a = b` is just a shorthand to `a.operator=(b)`, where operator= is a member function. And member functions can be called on rvalues such `(a * b)` created by `Rational::operator*`. To enforce similar semantics as for builtin rvalues ("**do as the ints do**") some authors (Meyers including) recommended in C++98 to return by const-rvalue for classes with such operators.

However, in C++11 returning by const-rvalue is a bad idea as it will inhibit move semantics because const rvalues cannot bind to `T&&`.

In his notes [**An overview of the new C++ (C++11)**](http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp), Scott Meyers gives precisely the same example from his old book, and concludes that it is now considered poor design to add the const return value. The recommended signature is now

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
```

**UPDATE:** As implied by @JohannesSchaub-litb in the comments, in C++11 you can also use a [reference qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/819272) on the assignment operator so that it will only accept lvalues as its left argument (i.e. the `*this` pointer, which is why this feature is also known as "rvalue references for *this"). You'll need g++ >= 4.8.1 (just released) or Clang >= 2.9 to make use of it.

Comment: The question is whether it is necessary to `const`-qualify the return value of `operator*` to prevent `(a * b) = c`. The question is not whether it is a good or bad idea to `const`-qualify the return value of `operator*`.

Comment: But wait, why don't define const move ctor like `T(const T&&)`?

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: because move semantics require a non-const object (how can you *move* -- ie. modify -- this object otherwise?).

Comment: @Barmaley.exe I don't know the ins and outs of moving, but to me `const` and moving seems like a contradiction.

Comment: @syam `mutable` would help.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: of course `mutable` would work but this defeats const-correctness: you'd have to make `mutable` pretty much every member of a movable class and then constness would have no meaning at all any more.

Comment: `mutable` would help, but is very likely inapropriate. `mutable` is intended for member variables that do not belong to the state of the object that is visible to the outside.

Comment: There is another question on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101647/1190430. @syam you needn't mark every member of class as mutable — it's sufficient to create boolean flag `isMoved` in order to not delete moved resources.

Comment: So the operator= of a user-defined class is not a typical assignment operator as for those built-in types. They behave a little different. Is this correct?

Comment: @zoujyjs how user-defined assignment operators behave is up to their implementation. The point is that in general they should behave as similar as possible as they do for builtins. But because for class types they can also be called on rvalues, it used to be recommended to make rvalues const to inhibit such assignments.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe: Well for once I don't agree at all with Andy (and his answer you linked to). You can bend the language into doing all sort of things, but bending the semantics is plain evil. Moving means modifying the visible state of both objects (moved-from/to), `const` means you can't modify the visible state, that's simply incompatible semantics-wise. Just because you can shoot yourself in the foot doesn't mean you should.

Comment: The proper way to forbid that assignment is `Rational &operator=(const Rational& other) &;`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, Would you say that should be the default way to declare it now unless you want the different semantics (assuming a compiler that implements it)?

Answer (score 8):

The const modifier on the return value is not necessary and can hinder move semantics.  The preferred way of preventing assignment to rvalues in C++11 is to use "[ref-qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)."

```
struct Rational
{
  Rational & operator=( Rational other ) &; // can only be called on lvalues
};

Rational operator*( Rational const & lhs, Rational const & rhs );

Rational a, b, c;

(a * b) = c; // error
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is going to cost me rep points, but I disagree. Don't modify the expected return types of overloaded operators as it will annoy users of your class. i.e. use

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
```

(Of course, `const`ing the *parameters* is good practice, and having constant reference parameters is even better as it means the compiler will not take deep copies. But don't have a constant reference return value in this case though as you'll get a *dangling reference* which is catastrophic. But do note that sometimes, taking a reference is slower than a pass by value. I think that `double`s and `int`s come into that category on many platforms.)

Comment: A reference return type for `operator*` would be somewhat odd...

Comment: Maybe you can explain why it's better for the return value to be non-const? Otherwise, this answer isn't worth much. How will this "annoy users of your class"?

Comment: You might want to write `a = (b * c).some_method_that_is_faster_on_non_const_self()`. But I admit I've never come across that situation.

Comment: Oli: I've edited my answer now and made it clear that I don't mean having a return reference!

Comment: The question is about having a const value return type, not a const reference return type. So this answer doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: What's a waffle?? And the question is about the return type, as evidenced by the last paragraph. In any case, your "answer" is just a personal opinion without any justification for it, just some vague mention of "annoying users" without explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

Because you might be intended to write `(a * b) == c` instead i.e.

```
if ((a * b) = (c + d)) // executes if c+d is true
```

But you wanted to

```
if ((a * b) == (c + d)) // executes if they're equal
```

Comment: This is something that compiler warnings should diagnose, disabling move semantics to avoid this problem is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you would like to do according to your question is to declare the corresponding operator= private such that it is not accessible anymore.

hence you would like to overload the signature that matches `(a*b) = c`.
I agree that the left part is an expression and therefore an rvalue would be a better match.
however you are ignoring the fact that this is the return value of the function if you overload the function to return an rvalue it the compiler will complain about an invalid overloading as overloading rules don't consider return values.

As stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) the operator overload for assignment is always an inside class definition. if there would be a non-member signature like `void operator=(foo assignee, const foo& assigner);` the overload resolution could match the first part as an rvalue (then you could delete it or declare it private).

So you can choose from two worlds:

- live with the fact that users can write stupid stuff like `(a*b) = c` which is not wrong but stores the value of c in an unaccessible temporary
- use the signature `const foo operator*(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)` which dissallows the `(a*b) = c` and sacrifice move semantics

### code

```
#include <utility>

class foo {
    public:
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo& f) = default;
    foo operator*(const foo& rhs) const {
        foo tmp;
        return std::move(tmp);
    }
    foo operator=(const foo& op) const {
        return op;
    }
    private:
    // doesn't compile because overloading doesn't consider return values.
    // conflicts with foo operator=(const foo& op) const;
    foo && operator=(const foo& op) const; 
};


int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    foo t2,t1;
    foo t3 = t2*t1;
    foo t4;
    (t2 * t1) = t4;
    return 0;
}
```