# What's a use case for overloading member functions on reference qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference, qualifiers

C++11 makes it possible to overload member functions based on reference qualifiers:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void f() &;   // for when *this is an lvalue
  void f() &&;  // for when *this is an rvalue
};

Foo obj;
obj.f();               // calls lvalue overload
std::move(obj).f();    // calls rvalue overload
```

I understand how this works, but what is a use case for it?

I see that [N2819](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2819.html) proposed limiting most assignment operators in the standard library to lvalue targets (i.e., adding "`&`" reference qualifiers to assignment operators), but [this was rejected](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#941). So that was a potential use case where the committee decided not to go with it. So, again, what is a reasonable use case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a class that provides reference-getters, ref-qualifier overloading can activate move semantics when extracting from an rvalue. E.g.:

```
class some_class {
  huge_heavy_class hhc;
public:
  huge_heavy_class& get() & {
    return hhc;
  }
  huge_heavy_class const& get() const& {
    return hhc;
  }
  huge_heavy_class&& get() && {
    return std::move(hhc);
  }
};

some_class factory();
auto hhc = factory().get();
```

This does seem like a lot of effort to invest only to have the shorter syntax

```
auto hhc = factory().get();
```

have the same effect as

```
auto hhc = std::move(factory().get());
```

EDIT: I found the [original proposal paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1821.htm), it provides three motivating examples:

1. Constraining `operator =` to lvalues (TemplateRex's answer)
2. Enabling move for members (basically this answer)
3. Constraining `operator &` to lvalues. I suppose this is sensible to ensure that the "pointee" is more likely to be alive when the "pointer" is eventually dereferenced:

```
struct S {
  T operator &() &;
};

int main() {
  S foo;
  auto p1 = &foo;  // Ok
  auto p2 = &S();  // Error
}
```

Can't say I've ever personally used an `operator&` overload.

Comment: `huge_heavy_class&& get() &&` is wrong (causes a dangling reference, shoukd be `huge_heavy_class get() &&`), and `auto hhc = std::move(factory().get());` would be redundant.

Comment: @ildjarn Why are you concerned about returning an rvalue reference, and not about returning an lvalue reference? One is no more likely to dangle than another. And yes, the point of the post is that it's a lot of code to write to avoid needing to write `std::move(factory().get())` - I suppose I need to make that clearer.

Comment: Because the lvalue reference is only returned for lvalues, and thus isn't a problem...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because it summarizes the situation well, and it links to the original proposal.

Answer (score 14):

One use case is to [prohibit assignment to temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16834937/819272)

```
 // can only be used with lvalues
 T& operator*=(T const& other) & { /* ... */ return *this; } 

 // not possible to do (a * b) = c;
 T operator*(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return lhs *= rhs; }
```

whereas not using the reference qualifier would leave you the choice between two bads

```
       T operator*(T const& lhs, T const& rhs); // can be used on rvalues
 const T operator*(T const& lhs, T const& rhs); // inhibits move semantics
```

The first choice allows move semantics, but acts differently on user-defined types than on builtins (doesn't do as the ints do). The second choice would stop the assigment but eliminate move semantics (possible performance hit for e.g. matrix multiplication).

The links by @dyp in the comments also provide an extended discussion on using the other (`&&`) overload, which can be useful if you want to *assign to* (either lvalue or rvalue) references.

Comment: More generally: Prevent exposing a reference or pointer to internal data of a temporary.

Comment: When would you ever *want* them to be assignable?

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't know, but if you don't specify the `&`, they will be.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Interesting. I feel like this could have been solved by prohibiting an rvalue from being assignable via `= rhs` altogether, instead of by introducing this much more general construct. If people really wanted to assign to rvalues they could just do `.operator=(rhs)` instead.

Comment: @Mehrdad that may have been less surprising at the cost of complicating the life of compiler writers :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex: I mean their life is already complicated by the fact that the two aren't equivalent anyway. You can't do `int.operator=(int)` so it's not like they can blindly transform it into `int = int`, they might as well check this too.

Answer (score 3):

If f() needs a Foo temp that is a copy of this and modified, you can modify the temp `this` instead while you can't otherwise

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand you can use them to prevent functions that are semantically nonsensical to call on temporaries from being called, such as `operator=` or functions that mutate internal state and return `void`, by adding `&` as a reference qualifier.

On the other hand you can use it for optimizations such as moving a member out of the object as a return value when you have an rvalue reference, for example a function `getName` could return either a `std::string const&` or `std::string&&` depending on the reference qualifier.

Another use case might be operators and functions that return a reference to the original object such as `Foo& operator+=(Foo&)` which could be specialized to return an rvalue reference instead, making the result movable, which would again be an optimization.

TL;DR: Use it to prevent incorrect usage of a function or for optimization.