# C++ Why should each function have a reference qualifier when defining overloads and reference functions

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I can't understand ：Why if a member function has a reference qualifier, all versions with the same list must have a reference qualifier.
Is it because multiple definitions are created when this function is called?

```
class A{
   public:
         A sorter() &&;
         A sorter();
         A operator+ (const A&);
       }
```

Although there is only function declaration above, it should be enough

```
A a , b;
(a+b).sorter();
```

Does the definition and calling of a function like the above make the compiler unable to recognize which member function to use？

Comment: It is the same for regular parameters: `void f(int)` versus `void f(int&&)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one overload is reference-qualified, the others must be as well.  This works:

```
     A sorter() &&;
     A sorter() &;
```

Put another way: you can choose between two sets of possible overloads:

1. `const` and non-const (unqualified).
2. `const&` (synonymous with `const` in 1), `&` (non-const), and `&&` (rvalue/temporary).

Comment: That's what I'm asking about，What's the meaning of doing this? To eliminate syntax errors, if only one member function is defined with a reference, will double definitions be created? Or just the syntax of C + +

Comment: @Nater: This is because a unqualified member function corresponds to both `&` and `&&`, i.e. it would be ambiguous.  For more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389911/why-is-overloading-on-just-one-ref-qualifier-not-allowed