# Member function return rvalue reference of member variable

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, xvalue

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct TempData {
    vector<int> data;
    TempData() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) data.push_back(i);
    }
    // vector<int> GetData() { // function 1
    //  return move(data);
    // }
    vector<int>&& GetData() { // function 2
        return move(data);
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    {
        TempData td;
        v = td.GetData();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between `function 1` and `function 2`?

Will `function 1` construct a temp `vector` with `move(data)` and then assign the temp `vector` to `v`?

No more details to add...

Comment: One function returns a new vector, the other does not.

Comment: You should consider overloading on reference qualifiers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052377/whats-a-use-case-for-overloading-member-functions-on-reference-qualifiers

Comment: If you need to do this, you should consider passing the object in, then you don't need it handed back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your little test case there is likely no difference. The extra temporary object will almost certainly be elided. And the `v` in main will hold the contents of the member variable.

But in the general case:

Version 1 will *definitely* leave the member `data` in some unspecified "empty" state. Even when the function return value is discarded.

Version 2 *may* leave the member in some unspecified empty state, or it may not. For instance, if the function is called and its return value discarded, the member will be unchanged. This is why it can be said that `std::move` by itself doesn't move anything.