# Good way to prevent C++03 code from performing suboptimally in C++11?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, move-semantics

I had some C++03 code that implemented `swap` for certain classes, to make `std::sort` (and other functions) fast.

Unfortunately for me, `std::sort` now seems to use `std::move`, which means my code is now **much slower** than it was in C++03.

I know I can use `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` to conditionally define a move-constructor/move-assignment operator, but I'm wondering if there's a better way that doesn't use preprocessor hacks?

(I'd like to avoid the proprocessor hacks because they would be ugly, since not only do I have to test for compiler versions like `_MSC_VER >= 1600`, but also because they wouldn't work well with tools like [LZZ](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) that don't recognize C++11 move syntax but force me to preprocess the code.)

Comment: Don't define any special members at all and just let them be generated (by using the appropriate building blocks)?

Comment: sadly, `std::sort` is not mandated to use `swap`, so how would it help?

Comment: @Xeo: Unfortunately Visual C++ doesn't auto-generate move members.

Comment: @TemplateRex: I'm not sure, do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: I think moving can be implemented in terms of swapping with a temporary. This is just a hack, but you could provide special iterators or wrappers providing this kind of move construction / assignment. (It might be tricky for classes that cannot be efficiently default-constructed.)

Comment: Don't write code that inhibits move semantics, the one thing I can think of right now is [not to return by const value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16834937/819272)

Comment: @Mehrdad it doesn't automatically add them... YET, it will in one of the upcoming updates

Comment: @Mgetz [VS2013 Nov13 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx) (which may not be used everywhere because it's only a preview)

Comment: @dyp I know, hence the *YET* as it will likely be released as part of update 2 or 3.

Comment: @Mgetz no, CTP with compiler updates will only make in the next RTM release

Comment: @dyp: Whoa, I didn't know there was a CTP for VS2013, thanks for that link!

Comment: @dyp: I installed the CTP but I'm not exactly sure what changed... seems like the same compiler as before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the question really is: how can a move constructor and move assignment be implemented with a C++03 compilers?

The simple answer is: they can't! However, the simple answer neglects the possibility of creating something which is perfectly valid C++03 code and which become move constructor and move assignment with a C++11 compiler. This approach will need to use some preprocessor hackery but that bit is only used to create a header defining a few tools used for the actual implementation.

Here is a simple header file which happily compiles without any warnings with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with C++11 enabled or disabled:

```
// file: movetools.hpp
#ifndef INCLUDED_MOVETOOLS
#define INCLUDED_MOVETOOLS
INCLUDED_MOVETOOLS

namespace mt
{
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
    template <typename T>
    class rvalue_reference {
        T* ptr;
    public:
        rvalue_reference(T& other): ptr(&other) {}
        operator T&() const { return *this->ptr; }
    };
#else
    template <typename T>
    using rvalue_reference = T&&;
#endif

    template <typename T>
    rvalue_reference<T> move(T& obj) {
        return static_cast<rvalue_reference<T> >(obj);
    }
}

#endif
```

The basic feature is to define a template `mt::rvalue_reference<T>` which behaves somewhat like an rvalue reference in C++03 and actually *is* an rvalue reference (i.e., a `T&&`) for C++11. It won't quite deal with C++03 rvalue references but, at least, allows to have move constructors and move assignments defined without actually needing rvalue references.

Note that `mt::move()` is just used to later show how `rvalue_reference<T>` can be moved even in C++03! The main point is that `rvalue_reference<T>` is either something a C++03 compiler understands or `T&&`. For this quite reasonable notation it is necessary that the compiler support alias templates. If that isn't the case, the same trick can be applied but using a suitable nested type of a corresponding class template.

Here is an example use of this header:

```
#include "movetools.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    foo() { std::cout << "foo::foo()\n"; }
    foo(foo const&) { std::cout << "foo::foo(const&)\n"; }
    foo(mt::rvalue_reference<foo> other) {
        std::cout << "foo::foo(&&)\n";
        this->swap(other);
    }
    ~foo() { std::cout << "foo::~foo()\n"; }
    foo& operator= (foo const& other) {
        std::cout << "foo::operator=(foo const&)\n";
        foo(other).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    foo& operator= (mt::rvalue_reference<foo> other) {
        std::cout << "foo::operator=(foo&&)\n";
        this->swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(foo&) {
        std::cout << "foo::swap(foo&)\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f0;
    foo f1 = f0;
    foo f2 = mt::move(f0);
    f1 = f2;
    f0 = mt::move(f1);
}
```

That is, the actual business logic is devoid of any preprocessor hackery. The only need to faff about with the preprocessor is in the header `movetools.hpp` which doesn't need to be messed with. That is, I actually think it does *not* use preprocessor hacks to define the actual move constructor or move assignment although the preprocessor is used somewhere. If you insist that you don't want to use macro hackery, it can be done by directing the compiler to look at different headers but that's an implementation detail of the `movetools.hpp`.

Comment: @dyp: Not the `mt::move()` is _only_ used in the example to show how the move constructor and move operator is called! The point is: for something which has rvalue references and alias templates (e.g., a C++11 compiler; without alias templates the same can be done using a nested type, though), the functions using `mt::rvalue_reference<T>` as parameters actually take `T&&` as parameter. That is, the goal is _exactly_ addressed by your second comment!

Comment: I'll retract that comment, was a bit confused. It's actually quite a nice solution. (You don't even have to provide pseudo-move support in C++03 mode, those ctors just have to compile.)

Comment: The compiler supports `move`: it just does not auto generate move ctors.

Comment: +1 thanks :) not perfect but I don't really expect there's a better way so I'll look into this.

Comment: @Yakk: the somewhat C++11 enabled compiler does support move construction and move assignment. However, the code is meant to also compile with a C++03 compiler which doesn't understand rvalue references. Using the approach I described the C++03 compiler can compile the code which turns into move constructor and assignment with a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/move.html). It has move emulation for c++03. Maybe it can help, but I didn't take a look at the details.

Comment: +1 Yeah I've seen it before, but using Boost is way overkill for what I want here.