# C++11 vs C++98 conversion operator behavior changes?

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, libstdc++, libc++

I'm looking to use some c++11 features in some existing c++ projects, so I started changing compile flags in Clang for some projects, and I keep running into a specific issue regarding C++11's treatment of conversion operators (or cast operators) that I didn't expect to see and don't understand why this is now considered an error when it's been valid C++ code that's not c++11

I've boiled it down to this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SerializableFormat
{
public:
    size_t i;
};

class A
{
public:
    size_t x, y;

    A(size_t n) : x(n), y(1) { }

    operator const SerializableFormat() const
    {
        SerializableFormat result;

        result.i = x;

        if (y)
        {
            result.i /= y;
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<SerializableFormat> v;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(A(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- If Clang's compilation flags are set to `-std=c++98` and `libstdc++`, there are no issues and this compiles fine.
- If Clang's compilation flags are set to `-std=c++11` and `libc++`, I get the error `No viable conversion from 'A' to 'value_type' (aka 'SerializableFormat')`

Just to make it clear-- in case you're thinking about giving SerializableFormat a constructor just for the class `A`:

Since the `SerializableFormat` class is more suited for conversion to and from various classes, it makes sense for `A` (and other classes that wish to be serializable) to have constructors and conversion operators rather than expect `SerializableFormat` to cover every type of class that wants to be serializable, so modifying `SerializableFormat` to have a special constructor is not a solution.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: With GCC, libstdc++, and `-std=c++11`, it still compiles. There is no point in your conversion operator returning `const SerializableFormat` -- just return `SerializableFormat` instead, and it'll also work with clang -- but I don't have an answer as to whether your code is valid.

Comment: I didn't notice the LLVM tag until just now. That changes things.

Comment: Minimal testcase: `struct A { }; struct B { operator const A(); }; void f() { (A(B())); }` gets accepted by GCC in all modes, by clang only in C++03 mode.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16834937/819272

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the comments correctly note, you can get compiling by dropping the `const` in the return type of your `SerializableFormat` conversion operator:

`operator` <del>`const`</del> `SerializableFormat() const`

As to whether clang is correct in this behavior is a matter of some dispute.  The issue is being tracked by [clang bug report 16682](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16682).  At this time there is talk of creating a CWG (C++ committee) issue report, but that has not yet been done.  I note that this bug report has been open for some time now (2013-07-23), but was updated as recently as 2015-01-28.

In the meantime, practical advice is just never to return by `const`-value.  This was decent advice for C++98/03, but with move semantics becomes bad advice because it will disable move semantics.

Comment: Why would you find it necessary to return a `const` object in the first place? You're constructing it on the spot, there's no need to protect it. If you were returning a *reference* that would be another matter.

Comment: @MarkRansom: In C++98/03 one guideline recommended always returning by `const` to prevent accidental assignment to an rvalue (the compiler prevents it if the rvalue is `const`).  This guideline was immortalized in Scott Meyers Effective C++ Item 3.