# return value of post-increment

Tags: c++, c++14

I have seen some answers about proper declaration of post-increment operator

```
T operator++(int);
```

most choose to return value. "Exceptional C++" suggests to return const value to prevent usage of the result as l-value.

> Postincrement should return a const value—in this case, const Complex. By not allowing changes to the returned object, we prevent questionable code like `a++++`, which doesn't do what a naïve user might think it does."

Quick search has found this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/6306106/8491726 - if I understand correctly adding const will now-days prevent usage of the return value as argument for move semantics. So the introduction of move  operations deprecates the suggestion from 1999 Book.

The question is - what is the proper way to achieve same result as recommended by "Exceptional C++" in the C++14?

Comment: My recommendation would be to return `T` and if someone wants to do something silly like `a++++` that's their own problem

Comment: so what does `a++++` do and what does a naive user think it does?

Comment: Is it really sensible to define the postincrement for some `Complex` class?

Comment: @Walter As a general rule Stroustrup suggests this: "Consider omitting postfix ++ and −− in a design." So probably in most cases we can get away without this operator at all. About a++++ - first operator returns temp value, so second will return same value and increment previous temp value. and a will be incremented only once.

Comment: @Walter A naive user probably thinks it double increments `a`, whereas it actually single-increments `a`, twice (as-in, it increments `a` then increments a copy of `a`).

Comment: Such a user is not naive, but ignorant.

Comment: Don't waste your time on this. Once you return your value to the user, it's theirs. Applying `const` to return values inhibits various optimizations as well, so you're just hurting people that aren't dumb. Also, if calling `operator++` on an rvalue is truly bad, _that's a totally separate problem_ and it's not your function's responsibility to fix that.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. My current version of the test class is available here https://gist.github.com/artemyv/4d4695dc293e81d86256ce0183ae3ba5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can forbid post increment of an rvalue:

```
T operator++(int) && = delete;
```

You must qualify original overload with `&`:

```
T operator++(int) & { /*...*/ }.
```

Comment: Is there any need for this overload if you just restrict the post increment to lvalues?

Comment: @juanchopanza The question is asking how to return values in such a way that post-increment cannot be used on the returned value. Both restricting post-increment to lvalues and preventing post-increment on rvalues solve that problem, don't they?

Comment: I was unable to add this overload to a simple test class  - gcc5.4 failed to compile it. https://gist.github.com/artemyv/4d4695dc293e81d86256ce0183ae3ba5 What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky You must qualify original overload with `&`: `Test operator++(int) & { /*...*/ }`. In fact, as hvd suggests, you don't need to to delete rvalue version at all, just qualifying lvalue one is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was enough to change the original overload to & version. I have updated gist based on the suggestion - so far the class works as desired.

Comment: @hvd The post-increment is just an *example* of a modification of the return value. This doesn't prevent all the other ones.

Comment: @juanchopanza All the other ones can be disabled the same way.

Comment: @hvd 1. That isn't what this answer proposed and 2. that isn't a good, scalable solution.

Comment: @juanchopanza Given that the same person who posted this answer had initially posted a now-deleted answer about preventing assignment to rvalues, I think that's exactly what this answer proposes. I don't see why it wouldn't scale. It brings the class closer to how built-in types such as `int` have worked since day one.

Comment: @hvd: Who says we want to mimic built-in types? Maybe it's the built-in types that are wrong? :)